# Get sftp file size using renci.sshnet

Tags: vb.net, ssh.net

I was trying to check the size of a file before I download it using renci.sshnet in vb.net. The only thing I notice is the .length always return a value of 4096 but the actual file is 700mb. Could someone help me get the accurate file size?

```
Dim sftpfile = sftp.ListDirectory("/Data/fdb")
For Each ftpFile In sftpfile
If FileSize > (i want to check those higher than 50mb) Then
'output file size
End If
Next
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to get a reference to the file as an SftpFile object. Then you can access the size attribute. Here's how in C# (converting to VB.NET shouldn't be hard):

```
SftpFile file = sftpClient.Get(filePath);
return file.Attributes.Size;
```

What you're probably reading is the internal buffer size (4096) which you shouldn't worry about.